# bazel - writable archivable path for test runtime

Tags: java, bazel, e2e-testing

I'm running E2E test using some bazel test target (the scala flavour of `java_test`).

In Maven I used to dump logs to `target/logs` folder that was created during test time, and then if something failed - I could have looked in this folder and find the logs.

In bazel - what path can I put in my test logs configuration so it would be writable and conveniently available upon test finish / test failure?

---

I know that the `java.io.tmp` dir is writable but gets deleted immediately after test finishes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So digging through bazel docs I found this:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#initial-conditions

Seems like I can read env variable `"TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR"` and it will give me a writable path. Anything I write there would be zipped and saved under `./bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/<package-name>/<target-name>/test.outputs/outputs.zip`

Pretty cool!

Comment: Stumbled upon this as well, as I wanted to preserve output from `py_test` rules. Asked a question, found your Q&A, solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417450/bazel-and-py-test-in-sandbox-any-way-to-define-outputs/54457113#54457113

Answer (score 0):

You can set a writable path for bazel test by using the environment variable TEST_TMPDIR="<.file directory.>".