# Writing file out of bazel test

Tags: bazel

I am interested in allowing an integration test (which is being run by bazel test) to write a file to a file location outside of the bazel cache (somewhere in a user's file system).  This is not an issue with bazel run, but we are unable to write during bazel test (which seems to be an intentional feature of bazel as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764221/how-to-write-files-to-current-directory-instead-of-bazel-out)).

In case the context helps, I want to record a replay file of the integration test, and actually commit it to source control.

Does anybody know of a solution to this within Bazel,or at least an override/workaround?

Comment: Are you looking for a one time thing or a methodical solution?

Comment: I found a solution, thanks.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883878/6917805

Comment: This will solve it as a one time thing, right?