# Bazel and py_test in sandbox - any way to define outputs?

Tags: pytest, bazel

I'm running multiple `py_test()` configurations on number of projects. Since there's a plenty of them, the default sandboxing mechanism seems convenient - tests don't intrude one another, and run in parallel for free.

This comes with a cost, though, as to my understanding sandboxing will cause bazel to run the tests in temporary directories. Combined with `py_test` rule not defining any *outs* parameter (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html), this likely means no generated file will be preserved after the test.

What I want to achieve, are two things:

1. Preserve output of the test, split by test case (I think I can get it to work using `capsys` and explicitly writing to a file named similarly to the test name). The problem here is, the file will end up in a sandboxed directory, i.e.: 
   `/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/12342134213421342134/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/project_name/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/test_suite.runfiles/`
   and will be removed afterwards.
2. I would like to get a run tests summary in an XML format. Bazel by itself generates an XML file in JUnit format, which would be fine, but unfortunately it does not work properly (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3413). The easiest solution would be to provide a parameter `--junitxml=path` (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files) which works, but again - generates a file in the temporary, sandboxed directory.

Other rules in bazel define *outs* as the files that they will generate, i.e. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html#predefined_genrule_variables: `genrule` contains an *outs* parameter.

So the question boils down to this: **is there any way in bazel to reuse (or wrap around) `py_test` rule and define some output files it will generate?**

Comment: Specifically for the junit output, you should use the environment variable `XML_OUTPUT_FILE` to pytest's `--junitxml` flag, and then bazel will use that file instead of its own junit xml file generator.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of experimenting with Bazel, I came to conclusion there's no easy to way to extend `py_test` to add outputs to it. It would also be rather difficult to create my own rule from scratch.

However, turns out all tests in Bazel define some environment variables that *could* be used. In fact, another, similar question was asked about this that solved the problem using them: [bazel - writable archivable path for test runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871993/bazel-writable-archivable-path-for-test-runtime)

In my tests I run pytest from within Python, so it is easy to programmatically extend startup arguments:

```
def _get_log_file_args():
    # Prepare the path to the log file, based on environmental
    # variables defined by Bazel.
    #
    # As per docs, tests should not rely on these variables
    # defined, so the framework will omit logging to file
    # if necessary variables are undefined.
    #   See: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#initial-conditions
    LOG_DIR_ENV_VARIABLE = "TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR"

    log_dir = os.environ.get(LOG_DIR_ENV_VARIABLE)
    if log_dir:
        file_log_path = os.path.join(log_dir, "test_output.log")
        return [f"--log-file={file_log_path}"]

    logger.warning(f"Environment variable '{LOG_DIR_ENV_VARIABLE}' used as the logging directory is not set. "
                    "Logging to file will be disabled.")
    return []  # no file logging
```

Then it's a matter of processing the final .zip archive at `./bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/<package-name>/<target-name>/test.outputs/outputs.zip` (according to the linked question).

Answer (score 3):

Just write xml output to the location specified in the `XML_OUTPUT_FILE` env variable. The file won't be zipped in this case.

From the source code here:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/test/test-setup.sh#L188

```
 if [ -n "${XML_OUTPUT_FILE-}" -a ! -f "${XML_OUTPUT_FILE-}" ]; then
    # Create a default XML output file if the test runner hasn't generated
```

I cannot hate bazel documentation enough, it's always driving me crazy.